# Does Lombok support not empty validation?

Tags: java, lombok

`@NonNull` only ensures not null, how to validate a collection that is not empty?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Brand {
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    // how to ensure not empty?
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lombok doesn't have that kind of annotation (see the [full list](https://projectlombok.org/features/all) of supported features).

You can use another library for that purpose. For example, [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) supports annotations like `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, `@Size()` among others.

Comment: By using Hibernate validator, `Brand brand = new Brand(null, null);` is still working, looks like the validation is not automatically triggered? How to make it auto triggered?

Comment: Another issue I ran into: If you use the non-lombok annotations like `@NotNull` the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and similar will include those fields.